Error in proof of Childress Class Field Theory, Theorem 7.2
Let $E = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, and $E^+ = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})$. Let $C_K$ denote the class group of a number field $K$. Theorem 7.2 of Childress states that the map $C_{E^+} \to C_E$ given by extending a representative of a class to $\mathcal{O}_E$ and then taking the corresponding ideal class is injective.
I am not bothered by the statement, but I can't understand the first line of the proof. The proof begins:

We must show that if $\mathfrak{a}\mathcal{O}_E$ is principal in $E$ then $\mathfrak{a}$ was principal in $E^+$ already. Say $$\mathfrak{a}\mathcal{O}_E = \langle \alpha \rangle$$ for $\alpha \in E$ and note that $\overline{\alpha} / \alpha$ is real[.]

I don't see how $\overline{\alpha} / \alpha$ can be real with only these assumptions. For example, taking $p = 3$, we have that $E^+ = \mathbb{Q}$. We can take the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ to be the trivial ideal $\mathbb{Z}$, and then $\mathfrak{a} \mathcal{O}_E = \mathcal{O}_E = \langle \zeta_3 \rangle$, but $\overline{\zeta_3} / \zeta_3 = \zeta_3^2 / \zeta_3 = \zeta_3$, which is not real.
Is the correct result that we can choose a generator $\alpha$ so that $\overline{\alpha} / \alpha$ is real? If so, how do you prove this?

This seems indeed like a mistake. The best we can say in the above situation is that $\overline{\alpha}$ generates the ideal $\overline{\mathfrak{a}\mathcal{O}_E}=\mathfrak{a}\mathcal{O}_E=\langle \alpha\rangle$.
Hence $\overline{\alpha}/\alpha$ is a unit of $E$. I think this implies that $\overline{\alpha}/\alpha = \zeta_p^t \cdot u$ for some integer $t$ and $u \in \mathcal{O}_{E^+}^{\times} \subset \mathbb{R}$.
